# How can I make an interactive Ruby program nicer?

Tags: ruby

(Windows 7 x64 running Ruby 1.9.3)

Here's the situation: I've made text game in Ruby, and I'm using the traditional `gets` method to get input from the user. When something is happening in the game (i.e. stuff is being printed to the screen), whatever the user has typed for input gets lost and the user has to continue typing what he/she has typed  on a new line. What he/she has originally typed before it got lost is still there, just doesn't get shown.

If the above didn't make sense try executing this code, and you'll see the problem:

```
Thread.new do
    loop do
        puts "Hello!"
        sleep 2
    end
end

Thread.new do
    loop do
        gets
    end
end
```

What I want is the line printed (in this case `"Hello!"`) to be placed before the line the user is typing into.

I understand that to achieve this I might need to delve into the Windows API. It may even be impossible. But if there's a way, I'd really like to know.

Comment: Ruby's `Curses` module might be of service: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html

Comment: @PeteSchlette Ah, Thanks. I'll have a look at that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most useful libraries for creating interactive terminal programs are [Curses](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) and [Readline](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html). The former lets you move the cursor anywhere in the terminal, print in colors, create separate "windows", etc. The latter is essentially a robust alternative to `gets`, with command history and autocompletion like in `irb`.

If you want to use Curses with Threads, you can check out my [fork of Ruby](https://github.com/silverhammermba/ruby/tree/curses/ext/curses), which adds this functionality (as well as refactoring the entire curses library).

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to go with Curses because I'm patient and like the sound of it :)

Comment: Hrm... Readline doesn't solve the problem at all... in the example code I provided, it prints "Hello!" and prints a new line. I was hoping to find a way to get the "Hello!" line to be inserted before the line the Readline prompt was in :\

Comment: Yeah, readline doesn't handle cursor position. It only does input. Curses is the way to go but it doesn't support non-blocking reads for threading and it's basically a straight port of the C library (i.e. it's hideous to work with). If you're feeling ambitious, you can check out my `curses` fork of Ruby on github to compile a better organized, threaded, version of the library.